# Finding location of MSI components after installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Currently I have a set of MSIs built using WiX. During installation they take user input and make some changes to some app.config XML files.

I also have a WiX Burn managed bootstrapper application with the same fields that passes the user input down to the MSIs.

What I want to do now is load the existing config file during upgrades and pre-populate the fields in the BA for better UX.

If I know the GUID, the Component ID and the File ID of the config file is there a way I can find its location to to load at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

Is your bootstrapper application native or managed?  MSI exposes some API's and WiX DTF encapsulates them.  See functions such as:

[MsiGetComponentPath function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370112(v=vs.85).aspx)

You could also choose to have the installer write something like HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\COMPANY\PRODUCT\INSTALLDIR  if you want to keep it simpler.

Comment: Then it would be the ComponentInstallation class's Path property.

Comment: How can I get access to that?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.9\SDK\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll

Comment: I mean how can I load that object from the BA?

Comment: http://bryanpjohnston.com/2012/09/28/custom-wix-managed-bootstrapper-application/

Comment: I have the entire MBA built and running. I know that part. What I am un sure about is how to call MsiGetComponentPath from it. It doesn't seem to be exposed. I am going to look at this. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b13b4124-c06f-40a8-bd9a-cf4e4ad1fba2/locating-a-programs-installation-folder?forum=winformssetup

Comment: You don't need to P/Invoke MsiGetComponentPath.  You use the ComponentInstallation class.  It has a constructor that takes ComponentCode and ProductCode as arguments and then has a Path (get) property  that returns the path.   Take a look at DTF.chm found in your start menu from installing WiX.